# What sensors (GPIO) are connected | Java

Tags: java, raspberry-pi, sensors, raspberry-pi3, gpio

I have a server & a client written in Java.
The server (connected to a specific port) is on the Raspberry PI and the client is on my computer.
When I connect my Raspberry PI and it connects to the Internet, then I can run the client, it will listen to that specific port and send a String to it, if the comparison with the String on the server is OK, then the IP number from the Raspberry PI will be sent to the client.
This way I will know what IP number the Raspberry PI has, but to my question.

Can I also get the information of what sensors are connected and what GPIOs are in use?
What if I have 10 RPIs with 10 different sensors on different GPIOs, how can I get that information from any RPIs sent back to my computer?

Is there any framwork, APIs or libraries that will let me know what GPIOs are in use and sent that data back?

Thank you.

Comment: if you dont know about the sensors that will be used with the raspberry pi then there is no way to get notification or info about which pin and which sensor has been used. You must query

Comment: Ok. I thought that I could in some way look up the Voltage from the pins and see what pins are in use with that information.